# SQL `SELECT 'some string value' AS fieldname` equivalent in Powershell?

Tags: sql, powershell, alias, rosetta-code

In SQL I can go `SELECT actualField, "repeat" AS bs_repeated_value FROM Table1`

And I can repeat the `bs_repeated_value` field as many times as there are rows no matter what I name the field!

Now in a similar and like manner in Powershell I can...almost...do the same thing, except for what I mentioned above...

```
get-ADUser -SearchRoot 'boogers.com/Locations/Kleenex' | 
Where-Object { $_.TITLE -ne 'Snot' } | 
Select LastName,FirstName,Description,SamAccountName,Department,TITLE, @{'bs_repeated_value' = 'repeat' }
```

Is there no way to do this?

Comment: Just a calculated property, right? For example (untested - writing on mobile): @{Name='NewDepartment'; Expression={$_.Department}}

Comment: @Captain_Planet Thank you, but I just needed a repeated value.  I understand what you're doing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I'm doing this wrong...here is how it works, although it's a bit less elegant than say your SQL syntax...

```
get-ADUser -SearchRoot 'boogers.com/Locations/Kleenex' | 
Where-Object { $_.TITLE -ne 'Snot' } | 
Select LastName,FirstName,Description,SamAccountName,Department,TITLE, @{Name='bs_repeated_value';Expression={'repeat'}}
```

References:

- http://powershell-guru.com/powershell-tip-140-convert-string-to-title-case/
- https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/